DB Wrapper in TypeScript
I have inherited a terrible database without being able to refactor it. I was hoping to instead create a wrapper in TypeScript that I can use as an in-between that will allow me to perform simple functions. Things like GetObjectWithID or Delete, etc.
What I have done is create an Interface for every object I can retrieve from the database and stored these interfaces in interfaces.ts. Now I want to create the actual wrapper. I just don't know enough about JavaScript/TypeScript to do this in a coherent and nice way that isn't just a bunch of copy and pasting. I have the following with just a fetch as an example:
import UserInterface from 'interfaces.ts';
import db from 'the_database';

class DatabaseObject {
  private static objectClass: string;
  private constructor() {}

  static getObject(id: string): object {
    return db.fetch(this.objectClass, id)
  }
}

class User extends DatabaseObject {
  private static objectClass = User;
  
  getObject(id: string): UserInterface {
    return super.getObject(id); // ??? this is definitely wrong
  }

}

Now this is a pretty basic example, and I'm hoping I can be assisted with the correct way to go about this. The goal is I could import the static User class in some future piece of code, and have the fetch/get return an object that fits the User Interface. In more complicated examples, I may need to modify the object returned from the database to properly fit the corresponding interface. In my opinion, it makes sense for the wrapper classes to be static, as it isn't an object that needs to exist, but rather a place to store the relevant database calls pertaining to that particular class/interface.
For example, a piece of code using this wrapper could look like:
import UserInterface from 'interfaces.ts';
import User from 'db_wrapper.ts';

const myUserId: string = "abcd1234";
const myUser: UserInterface = User.getObject(myUserId);

console.log(myUser.username);
console.log(myUser.email);


I'm guessing you need something like this.constructor.getObject(id) (which won't easily type check) but I don't know why any of this needs to be static, exactly. Please [edit] to provide a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to work on this. Among other things that means you should provide declarations for any types and values your example depends on.

I can edit to be more clear, but I'll never be able to create a "minimal reproducible example" when the question is more about proper style than it is about solving a reproducible problem. I can however, provide a better example of how I want to use this wrapper.

I have faith that you can indeed provide a [mre] with fully-declared interfaces that we can play around with.

I have updated the question to contain a desired use-case example. The purpose of the question however, is to be interface dependant. Unless I misunderstand what an interface is. I could have used Types instead for example. But my question is asking what to do in the generic case.

Maybe we’re talking past each other? I’m asking you to give declarations for the UserInterface interface and probably some toy declaration for db also. It makes it a lot easier for us to show you how to do something if the example doesn’t fill our IDEs with errors unrelated to your question

(see prev comment) If I make guesses for UserInterface and db based on your examples, then my suggested approach looks something like this playground link. Instead of a class, we just have a function which wraps db. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (and probably [edit] the question to include those definitions). If not, please [edit] to show any functionality or requirements I'm missing here.
